# How to set up try-catch to ensure user enters a value that is contained within an enum list?

Tags: c#, enums

I've got an enum list for days of the week, and a program that asks the user to enter the current day (It can be any day on the list).  I need to implement a try-catch to ensure that the user enters a valid day, but I'm running into some confusion.

When I search up how to do exceptions with enums, most sites suggest using TryParse over try-catch, but for this specific assignment, I need to wrap this in a try-catch. Should I be using catch (OverflowException)? This doesn't seem to work because I'm unsure of what comes after that.  I tried to declare a variable right after OverflowException, as that's what I see in try-catch examples; however, I took it out because it gave me errors.  So far, I haven't been able to find an example similar to mine that uses try-catch, which I can learn from.

Could someone take a look at this program and help me with how to correctly include a try-catch to handle invalid input? I want the console to say "not a valid day" if the user enters anything other than Sunday through Saturday, which includes abbreviations.  Thank you!!

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the current day of the week.");
                string currentday = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Good job.  Today is " + currentday);
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
           catch(OverflowException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not a valid day");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public enum days
        {
            Sunday,
            Monday,
            Tuesday,
            Wednesday,
            Thursday,
            Friday,
            Saturday          
        }
```

Comment: Why do you only test for OverflowException?

Comment: Your current code does never throw an exception., since you don't convert the input.

Comment: Poul Bak  I wasn't sure what else to test for.  I saw OverFlow exception being used in an example online, so I thought I'd start there and see what happened.  Am I supposed to convert the input to enum?

Comment: Well, isn't that what you want? You can of course keep it as a string, then you won't get errors.

Comment: Thank you, Poul!  I'm so new I didn't even realize converting to enum was an option; I thought it should just stay a string, so I will keep it string as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [EnumTryParse Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/dd991317(v=vs.80)). You can actually remove the try-catch too.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the current day of the week.");
            string currentday = Console.ReadLine();
            days day;

            if (Enum.TryParse<days>(currentday, out day))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Good job.  Today is " + currentday);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new OverflowException(); // try parse failed. enum not valid! Why OverflowException?
            }
        }
        catch (OverflowException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not a valid day");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public enum days
    {
        Sunday,
        Monday,
        Tuesday,
        Wednesday,
        Thursday,
        Friday,
        Saturday
    }
}
```

OR

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the current day of the week.");
    string currentday = Console.ReadLine();
    days day;

    if (Enum.TryParse<days>(currentday, out day))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Good job.  Today is " + currentday);
    }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Not a valid day");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

EDIT:

Upon further inspection, @Nalaka526's answer is more suitable. Enum.TryParse will return true for unexpected inputs like "01", "111", etc. while Enum.IsDefined will only match the enum names.

Here is one way how you continue to prompt for the day until the input is valid.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool isValid = false;

    do {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the current day of the week.");
        string currentday = Console.ReadLine();

        isValid = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(days), currentday);

        if (isValid)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Good job.  Today is " + currentday);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not a valid day");
        }
    } while (!isValid);            

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, John!! These both look like great solutions and you've written them so they are easy for me to follow and understand.  This is perfect, thanks:)

Comment: Hello again John!  Not sure if you will see this, but I decided to go with your second solution, as it's easier for me to understand with my basic knowledge level.  I also want to prompt the user to enter a another day if their input was invalid.  Do you recommend a "do-while" loop in that situation?  I'm trying to put one in place, but it doesn't seem to be working because I'm unsure how to write a bool that looks at the enum list and evaluates valid input.  Is there a way to add that looping functionality in here?  Thank you again! Your help has been very valuable!

Comment: Thanks so much, John! This is so simple and concise. Most importantly, it works! Many thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Enum.IsDefined` (*without using Try/Catch*) to check whether the entered value is valid,

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the current day of the week.");
string currentday = Console.ReadLine();

if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(days), currentday))
    Console.WriteLine("Good job.  Today is " + currentday);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not a valid day");

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thanks, Nalaka!! This is such a concise and very helpful solution!  I'm starting to see the different ways of exception handling can be implemented:)